# How to get the pdf output vertically below the latex editor in Texstudio?

Tags: texstudio, layout

I am running two instances of Texstudio on my Windows 10. The problem is that the four columns compromise visibility (two for the editor and two for the output). Is there any way to get the outcome(pdf) pane below the latex editor pane (turning the screen into 4 almost square tabs) allowing more horizontal visibility in Textstudio?
[image]

Comment: I have been through some solutions with the windowed pdf viewer, but I want to do it somehow with the embedded pdf viewer. To keep one instance in one window.
Currently as shown, I am running two instances of Texstudio at once side by side.

Comment: You can get another screen to stretch things out horizontally.

Comment: TexStudio has no options to place the defined panes internally in another place, for example swapping the log/issue pane with the preview pane as you would like to do. So the only option is to use the Windows options to show four equally size panes using the windowed pdf viewer. You already mentioned that.

Comment: It is a good idea @Werner, but I, unfortunately, can't afford another screen at the moment.

Comment: You are right @alchemist, I tried to find something like a page layout or settings, but there are none. I think I am left only with the windowed viewer option then.